# Using Rcpp within parallel code via snow to make a cluster

Tags: r, rcpp, snow

I've written a function in `Rcpp` and compiled it with `inline`. Now, I want to run it in parallel on different cores, but I'm getting a strange error. Here's a minimal example, where the function `funCPP1` can be compiled and runs well by itself, but cannot be called by `snow`'s `clusterCall` function. The function runs well as a single process, but gives the following error when ran in parallel:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: NULL value passed as symbol address
```

And here is some code:

```
## Load and compile
library(inline)
library(Rcpp)
library(snow)
src1 <- '
     Rcpp::NumericMatrix xbem(xbe);
     int nrows = xbem.nrow();
     Rcpp::NumericVector gv(g);
     for (int i = 1; i < nrows; i++) {
      xbem(i,_) = xbem(i-1,_) * gv[0] + xbem(i,_);
     }
     return xbem;
'
funCPP1 <- cxxfunction(signature(xbe = "numeric", g="numeric"),body = src1, plugin="Rcpp")

## Single process
A <- matrix(rnorm(400), 20,20)
funCPP1(A, 0.5)

## Parallel
cl <- makeCluster(2, type = "SOCK") 
clusterExport(cl, 'funCPP1') 
clusterCall(cl, funCPP1, A, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Think it through -- what does inline do?   It creates a C/C++ function for you, then compiles and links it into a dynamically-loadable shared library.  Where does that one sit?  In R's temp directory.

So you tried the right thing by shipping the *R frontend calling that shared library* to the other process (which has another temp directory !!), but that does not get the dll / so file there.

Hence the advice is to create a local package, install it and have both snow processes load and call it.

(And as always: better quality answers may be had on the rcpp-devel list which is read by more Rcpp constributors than SO is.)

Comment: Makes perfect sense. For some reason, I assumed this was snow-specific, which is why I posted here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I stumbled across it while looking through the top Rcpp tags so maybe this answer will be of use still.

I think Dirk's answer is proper when the code you've written is fully de-bugged and does what you want, but it can be a hassle to write a new package for such as small piece of code like in the example. What you can do instead is export the code block, export a "helper" function that compiles source code and run the helper. That'll make the CXX function available, then use another helper function to call it. For instance:

```
# Snow must still be installed, but this functionality is now in "parallel" which ships with base r.
library(parallel)

# Keep your source as an object
src1 <- '
     Rcpp::NumericMatrix xbem(xbe);
     int nrows = xbem.nrow();
     Rcpp::NumericVector gv(g);
     for (int i = 1; i < nrows; i++) {
      xbem(i,_) = xbem(i-1,_) * gv[0] + xbem(i,_);
     }
     return xbem;
'
# Save the signature
sig <- signature(xbe = "numeric", g="numeric")

# make a function that compiles the source, then assigns the compiled function 
# to the global environment
c.inline <- function(name, sig, src){
    library(Rcpp)
    funCXX <- inline::cxxfunction(sig = sig, body = src, plugin="Rcpp")
    assign(name, funCXX, envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
# and the function which retrieves and calls this newly-compiled function 
c.namecall <- function(name,...){
    funCXX <- get(name)
    funCXX(...)
}

# Keep your example matrix
A <- matrix(rnorm(400), 20,20)

# What are we calling the compiled funciton?
fxname <- "TestCXX"

## Parallel
cl <- makeCluster(2, type = "PSOCK") 

# Export all the pieces
clusterExport(cl, c("src1","c.inline","A","fxname")) 

# Call the compiler function
clusterCall(cl, c.inline, name=fxname, sig=sig, src=src1)

# Notice how the function now named "TestCXX" is available in the environment
# of every node?
clusterCall(cl, ls, envir=.GlobalEnv)

# Call the function through our wrapper
clusterCall(cl, c.namecall, name=fxname, A, 0.5)
# Works with my testing
```

I've written a package [ctools](https://github.com/bamonroe/ctools) (shameless self-promotion) which wraps up a lot of the functionality that is in the parallel and Rhpc packages for cluster computing, both with PSOCK and MPI. I already have a function called "c.sourceCpp" which calls "Rcpp::sourceCpp" on every node in much the same way as above. I'm going to add in a "c.inlineCpp" which does the above now that I see the usefulness of it.

### Edit:

In light of Coatless' comments, the `Rcpp::cppFunction()` in fact negates the need for the `c.inline` helper here, though the `c.namecall` is still needed.

```
src2 <- '
 NumericMatrix TestCpp(NumericMatrix xbe, int g){
        NumericMatrix xbem(xbe);
        int nrows = xbem.nrow();
        NumericVector gv(g);
        for (int i = 1; i < nrows; i++) {
            xbem(i,_) = xbem(i-1,_) * gv[0] + xbem(i,_);
        }
        return xbem;
 }
'

clusterCall(cl, Rcpp::cppFunction, code=src2, env=.GlobalEnv)

# Call the function through our wrapper
clusterCall(cl, c.namecall, name="TestCpp", A, 0.5)
```

Comment: Please do not use `cxxfunction`. Please use `cppFunction()` instead.

Comment: I think it could work just the same, I just wanted to use the original example. With `cppFunction()` the `src1` code block would be slightly different. Is there any particular reason not to use `cxxfunction`?

Comment: The end result is the same, but how you get there is different. In particular, the `cxxfunction()` present code in a non-function form way. Using `cppFunction()` I can write the C++ code in functional form, e.g.: `Rcpp::NumericMatrix sig(Rcpp::NumericMatrix xbem,  Rcpp::NumericVector gv){
     int nrows = xbem.nrow();
     for (int i = 1; i < nrows; i++) {
      xbem(i,_) = xbem(i-1,_) * gv[0] + xbem(i,_);
     }
     return xbem;
}`. The focus is more on the actual calculation than keeping track of inputs or casting objects.

Comment: In essence, many things have changed since the introduction of _Rcpp_ Attributes. It's a shame to see people not taking advantage of them.

Comment: Good point. I personally prefer working with individual source files and using `sourceCpp()`, so I've never had to make the distinction between the two inline-style functions. Answer updated using `cppFunction()`.

Comment: For those who come later, I decided to write a post about this... http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp/to-rcpp-attributes-and-beyond-from-inline/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by sourcing on each cluster cluster node an R file with the wanted C inline function:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, 
    {
     library(inline)
     invisible(source("your_C_func.R"))
    })
```

And your file your_C_func.R should contain the C function definition:

```
c_func <- cfunction(...)
```