# Cannot access parameters in C++ code in parallel code called from Snow

Tags: r, rcpp, snow

I am developing a parallel R code using the Snow package, but when calling C++ code using the Rcpp package the program just hangs and is unresponsive.

as an example...
I have the following code in R that is using snow to split into certain number of processes

```
    MyRFunction<-function(i) {
      n=i
      .Call("CppFunction",n,PACKAGE="MyPackage")
      }
    if (mpi) {
      cl<-getMPIcluster()
      clusterExport(cl, list("set.user.Random.seed"))  
      clusterEvalQ(cl, {library(Rcpp); NULL})
      out<-clusterApply(cl,1:mc.cores,MyRFunction)
      stopCluster(cl)
      }
    else
      out <- parallel::mclapply(1:mc.cores,MyRFunction)
```

Whereas my C++ function looks like...

```
    RcppExport SEXP CppFunction(SEXP n) {
      int n=as<int>(n);
      }
```

If I run it with mpi=false and mc.cores=[some number of threads] the program runs beautifully BUT
if i run it with mpi=true, therefore using snow, the program just hangs at int=as<int>(n) ?????
On the other hand if I define the C++ function as...

```
    RcppExport SEXP CppFunction(SEXP n) {
      CharacterVector nn(n);
      int n=boost::lexical_cast<int>(nn[0]);
      }
```

The program runs perfectly on each mpi thread?? The problem is that it works for integers doubles etc, but not matrices
Also, I must use lexical_cast from the boost package to make it works since as<> does not.

Does anybody know why this is, and what I am missing here, so I can load my matrices as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074310/snow-inline-rcpp?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the issue was resolved, and the problem seems to lie with getMPICluster() which works perfectly fine for pure R code, but not as well with Rcpp, as explained above.
Instead using makeMPICluster command

```
    mc.cores <- max(1, NumberOfNodes*CoresPerNode-1) # minus one for master
    cl <- makeMPIcluster(mc.cores)
    cat(sprintf("Running with %d workers\n", length(cl)))
    clusterCall(cl, function() { library(MyPackage); NULL })
    out<-clusterApply(cl,1:mc.cores,MyRFunction)
    stopCluster(cl)
```

Works great! The problem is that you have to manually define the number of nodes and cores per node within the R code, instead of defining it using the mpirun command.

Comment: You should edit your question rather than dumping a non-answer answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear from your question what you are doing but I'd recommend to

- simplify:  snow certainly works, and works with Rcpp as it does with other packages
- trust packages:  I found parallel computing setups easier when all nodes are identical local packages sets
- be careful with threading:  if you have trouble with explicit threading in the snow context, try it first without it and the add it once the basic mechanics work

Comment: I guess it isn't as identical to the question I referenced as I thought since you answered that one too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have asked the question in the Rcpp mailing list and hopefully someone knows what I am doing wrong

Comment: Well, I am am the owner/admin of that list so I'd tell you the same there (but there are other knowledgeable subscribers). Your post has not come through though, so make sure you are subscribed.

Comment: Thanks Dirk and have not posted on Rcpp yet, since waiting for confirmation to subscription, although as you can see above I have simplified the code so that it is clearer what the problem is.

Comment: There is no confirmation. You sign up first, then you can post.